# A new asset through a transaction hyperledger composer & an other question

Tags: javascript, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am designing the business network and I am implementing the logic.js for the network on hyperledger composer bluemix, I want to create an asset through a transaction in the logic.js file how to do that please? and I have another problem which is how to check a random number is not equal an old or active asset attribute in the transaction registry, I am creating a voucher consumption transaction and model.cto

```
asset Voucher identified by serial {
 o String serial
 o String Code //new code generated for every new consumption transaction
 o DateTime creationDate
 o Double amount
 o Typev type
 o Integer activated
}

enum Typev {
 o paperVoucher
 o giftVoucher
}
```

logic.js part of code:

```
do{
 var min=1;
 var max=999999;
 var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (+max - +min)) + +min;
}while (random!=//old serials or active serials); //missing random test with the old serials
```

Comment: As a side note, you should avoid storing non-deterministic values in your data. For example in your code if 2 peers run the same TP function at the same time (as part of a request from a client) then they would actually come back with different results, and if these 2 peers were in different organisations and an endorsement policy that both have to endorse exists then the transaction would fail to commit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first part of the question, refer to 
[Asset Creation through Transaction in Hyperledger Composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49744551/asset-creation-through-transaction-in-hyperledger-composer)

For your second part Check out Historian
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/business-network/historian